# Array,Reduce() function initiates before data is passed into it - results in NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to perform a simple addition based on user inputs ( for dimensions of a box in cubic meters.. i want to sum up all the boxes they want to add ).

```
  const totalW = []
  const cubitMeters = (parseInt(height) * parseInt(width) * parseInt(length) * parseInt(count)) / 1000000
  totalW.push(cubitMeters)
```

then in JSX I'm reducing it

```
  <Text>
    {totalW?.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0).toFixed(2)}
  </Text>
```

Everything is fine, however as you can see the calculation for `cubitMeters` is a multiplication.. and unless all numbers are provided, it returns NaN. And it only works properly when the user finally enters all numbers, which isn't ideal.

How can I make sure that the function only is triggered when all numbers are entered?

Comment: The error does not come from Array.prototype.reduce, but that your `totalW` array contains NaN values. Are you sure all the `parseInt()` statements are correctly returning numbers and not NaN?

Comment: hey @Terry no it's not.. i just console.logged ```totalW``` with 1 unfinished input and it returned 
```0: 0.24 - 1: NaN``` is there any way to prevent ```totalW.push(cubitMeters)``` from happening if it returns ```NaN```?

Comment: Do you have the calculation linked to a submit button or does it just autofill an answer field when all values are inputted? I'll quickly build a function for you.

Comment: if any of these isn't there ```(parseInt(height) * parseInt(width) * parseInt(length) * parseInt(count))``` from ```const cubitMeters``` it just returns NaN.. it's autofill/onChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in an if statement

```
if (totalW.length === 0) {
  return
} else {
  ///return your totalW value
}
```

Otherwise, build an async function to do the calculation and await the result. This may work

```js
const calculationFunction = async (err, response) => {
  let totalW = [];
  let calculation =
    (parseInt(height) * parseInt(width) * parseInt(length) * parseInt(count)) /
    1000000;
  if (calculation.length !== 0) {
    let cubitMeters = calculation;
    totalW.push(cubitMeters);
  } else {
    console.log("Not ready yet...");
  }
};

const answer = await calculationFunction();
```

Then do this:

```
if (answer.length > 0) {
  <Text>{answer?.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0).toFixed(2)}</Text>;
} else {
  console.log("Still calculating...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I really appreciate it. After talking with you, some things started to ring the bell and I finally came up with a solution.

```
    {totalW
       .filter((nan) => nan)
       .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
       .toFixed(2)}
```

This function basically filters out all falsy values ( and apparently NaN is a falsy value ).. once I got it figured out, it was a piece of cake

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!